# Help: Fantasy magic book series male genius similar to Name of the Wind

Tags: story-identification, magic

Can't recall book names or author or character names.

- Looking for a series (7-9 books).
- The first part of title was always the same as if it was a chronicle or Quest and vaguely remember something about time.
- Blue cover always with male character as if walking out of a tunnel with machinery/clockwork/swords etc. in background.
- Long titles
- Target audience was Young Adult
- I have spent days searching online, but can find zero reference to it.
- Book 1, he is discovering his magicalesque abilities.
- Black rubbery magical material he finds/uses.
- Reference to his grandfather who had died recently.
- There's a young girl (teen) Rebecca or Kate that he has a love interest in. She seemed very strong willed.
- He's from a wealthy background.
- His cousin is a prince that he has to protect - book 1 only.
- Political / war theme, but much more focused on the magical ability of the male protagonist.
- His father is someone important.
- The girl is training to be a soldier or assassin in some kind of guild.

He travels with an odd group to a factory where the baddies are making weapons. They hide in these animal shaped big statues on the garden grounds of this factory/castle through trap doors.

That's all I can think of; the books are brilliant and I can't REMEMBER and it's driving me nuts. I think it was published between 2000-2012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it. *[The Laws of Magic](https://www.goodreads.com/series/50241-the-laws-of-magic)* by Michael Pryor. Thanks for the advice guys - good to know for next time.

The first book is *[Blaze of Glory](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1831563.Blaze_of_Glory)*.

[image: Book Cover - Blaze of Glory]

> Aubrey Fitzwilliam is the son of a prominent ex-prime minister. He's also brilliant at magic, but he's stuck at military school. At least he has his best friend, George, there to back him up. George would follow Aubrey anywhere - and with Aubrey's talent for thinking up impulsive and daring schemes that will get them both in trouble, that's no easy thing to do.
>
> At a weekend shooting party at Prince Albert's country estate, the boys find themselves in a hotbed of intrigue and politics. They discover a golem, a magical creature built to perform one task: to kill Prince Albert. Aubrey and George are hailed as heroes for foiling the attempt on the prince's life - but who sent the golem, and why? Aubrey is far too curious to let the authorities handle this one, and he and George start investigating.